# Bootstrap Navbar Collapse not working when navbar position is absolute

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

When using `position: absolute;` the navbar collapse does not work properly. When expanding the menu, the other content is not moved down anymore. Also, the button to expand and collapse is not visible (which is why I have made it gray) and does not appear in the correct position.

[image: Screenshot showing issue]

HTML code for the navbar:

```
<nav class="bootstrap-iso navbar navbar-default navbar-absolute">
        <div class="container">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="bootstrap-iso navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">DEMO</a>
            </div>

            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">

                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" id="navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Bruid</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Bruidegom</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">De Winkel</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                    <li><button class="btn" id="afspraak">AFSPRAAK MAKEN</button></li>

                </ul>

            </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </nav>
```

CSS:

```
navbar-right li {
    font-family: Arial;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: bold;
}

#afspraak {
    margin-top: 5%;
    background-color: #f5758e;
    font-family: Arial;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: white;
}

#navbar-right a {
    color: white;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
    color: white !important;
    font-size: 36px !important;
}

.navbar-default {
    background: transparent !important;
    border: none !important;
    position: absolute;
}

.navbar-toggle {
   background-color: grey !important;
}
```

Many thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

YoungStarDC it happens to the best of us...check the first line of the navbar class. You need to add a '<' everything that's open has to be closed and everything that's closed has to be opened. The button will appear when you change the browsers window size once you do that.

```
<nav class="bootstrap-iso navbar navbar-default navbar-absolute"></nav>
```

P.S. Bootstraps navbar-collapse only collapses the navbar and shows the button when the screen is too small to hold the navbar

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but unfortunately that was not the issue! I just forgot to copy that part, sorry. :(

Comment: so you still don't get the button and the proper collapse when the page is reduced in size?

Comment: Have you tried removing either navbar-absolute from your html or from the CSS. It is redundant to have it in both places and I have had issues in the past with this same issue. Perhaps you could try putting position: relative for your collapsible menu in your CSS.

Comment: Both solutions don't work unfortunately. The reason I am trying to use position: absolute; is because it makes the navbar overlap with the image. When using position:relative; the navbar doesn't overlap with the image anymore.

Comment: I see...so you want that overlap, I like to do that sometimes as well, but I don't believe that will work with the navbar-collapsible. What I personally would have done was to make the collapsible div even with the image div and then used the z index to place it. However I found out that bootstrap has a thing called overflow for your CSS x and y overflow. maybe you can check that out, because I am learning bootstrap myself, but I am pretty familiar with HTML and CSS and I'm sure you have a positioning conflict there.